# How to connect two docker containers using etcd

Tags: docker, etcd

I have few docker containers and etcd docker container running in a machine. I want to have one of the docker container in another machine and connect it to etcd in the primary server using docker run.
i have provided the ETCD_client_port in docker run but i want to mention the etcd server ip too. What is the proper way to connect this container to the etcd server present in another machine but same network.